# Kohana app database not connecting

Tags: kohana

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Database_Mysqli' not found
MODPATH/database/classes/kohana/database.php [ 78 ]
73 
74          // Set the driver class name
75          $driver = 'Database_'.ucfirst($config['type']);
76 
77          // Create the database connection instance
78          new $driver($name, $config);
79      }
80 
81      return Database::$instances[$name];
82  }
83 
{PHP internal call} » Kohana_Core::shutdown_handler()
Environment
```

i tried everything doesnt work, can anyone help, i cant configure it, i can give remote access to see whats wrong

Comment: Try re-downloading the [database module](https://github.com/kohana/database) (just replace the folder in your /modules/ path)

Comment: Finally upload the mysqli driver in the module folder but all I get is blank screen no errors what should I do now?

Comment: check Kohana and server (Apache) log

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Can anyone help here?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Kohana logs are in /application/logs/ (sorted by year/month/date.php) and for server logs better use the search engine of your choice. Chances are (on webhosting), that you don't have access to server logs

Comment: Thanks can I pm u? Maybe u can look at it or do u have skype?

Comment: When I try to visit that it says  no direct script access

Comment: Errorexecption class database mysqli not found mod path/database/classes/kohana/database.php

Comment: im really stuck badly here can anyone help here

Comment: Have you tried setting up a new completely Kohana and just moving your data in application/?

Comment: Yes I moved the application folder still it was a blank screen

Comment: so i have finally downgraded the server to ubuntu 12.4 and installed php 5.3, how im getting the home page . finallyyyyyy but now the link are not working, URL not found in this server, but if i write index.php then it works, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

- As mentioned in comment download [enter link description here](https://github.com/kohana/database)
- In config -> database.php use type => 'MySQLi'

  Note: It looks like you typed it as Mysqli as In kohana 3.3 onward class name are case sensitive.